# Jenkins does not trigger pipeline job after push on git repository

Tags: git, github, webhooks, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I am trying to trigger a pipeline job after a push to my git repo.

- I am using the last version of jenkins
- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- Java:
  java version "1.8.0_121"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
- I already configure my credentials using secret text (token by github)
- My token has all the permissions
- The web hooks is set correctly in its place in github
- In my jenkins log I can see this after a push to my repo:

  Feb 01, 2017 9:41:31 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber onEvent
  INFO: Received PushEvent for https://github.com/xxxxxx/xxx

  But nothing happends.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you show us how you have configured your Jenkins job ? Have you checked the "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" option on your job configuration ?

Comment: Yes I have checked that option, but in resent versions that is now "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling"

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with the version jenkins version I installed today.

Comment: Hey @J.Ordaz Did you ever find the answer?